# How do you find the line and row content that triggered, Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

How do you find the line and row content that triggered that event when you do something from a view that triggers the event while developing a visual studio extension?

```
[Export(typeof(IWpfTextViewCreationListener))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
internal sealed class EditorListener : IWpfTextViewCreationListener
{
    [Import] private readonly IAsyncCompletionBroker _completionBroker = null;

    private IWpfTextView TextView { get; set; }

    public void TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)
    {
        TextView = textView;
        if (_completionBroker != null)
        {
            _completionBroker.CompletionTriggered += CompletionBroker_CompletionTriggered;
        }

    }

    private void CompletionBroker_CompletionTriggered(object sender, CompletionTriggeredEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
       // this find line and line content
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [System.Runtime.CompilerServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices?view=net-5.0) to get line number and line content:

```
    private void CompletionBroker_CompletionTriggered(object sender, CompletionTriggeredEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // this find line and line content
        TraceMessage();
    }

    public void TraceMessage(
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
    }
```

And you can `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` will show the message in output window

Comment: this visual studio works too, but something else is required during the extension development phase

Comment: Or you can try to use [TextSelection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.textselection?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)